# The current in an inductor, the voltage across it, faraday and lenz's law

Tags: electromagnetic-induction

Let's say there is an ideal AC voltage source connected to an ideal inductor.

The applied voltage is a sine wave. And the current must also be a sine wave(albeit only for an instant)

Deriving from what Faraday says, the voltage across an inductor is Ldi/dt. Now, since the current at the moment is a sine wave, the voltage across the inductor comes out to be a 90 degree leading sine wave.

Lenz says that the induced emf must oppose the cause. Therefore in this case must be perfectly out of phase with the 'faraday' waveform(90 degree lag).

1-Why are there three different waveforms here. If I measure the waveform with an imaginary oscilloscope, I would get the applied voltage. What are the other two telling waveforms telling us?

2-Why is the current lagging?

P.S: I understand the mathematical derivation, but I'm trying to understand it from a physics perspective. Also, I've taken a look at the other threads similar to this topic, and I'm not sure I understand the replies. They're all over the place.

Comment: *Why is the current lagging?* - Note that if the (ideal) inductor AC current and voltage were not in quadrature, there would be net energy dissipated or sourced over one cycle. When in quadrature, the net energy delivered to the inductor over one cycle is zero. Is this the kind of *physics perspective* you're looking for? If not, would you elaborate on what you mean by "physics perspective"?

Comment: @AlfredCentauri well, I understand that. But the voltage across an inductor is leading the applied voltage but I already know the voltage at that point which is the applied original sine wave. Its only we assume that the current is lagging in the first place, we get the sine wave using Ldi/dt. This is not clear to me.

Comment: the voltage across the inductor *is* the applied voltage so I don't know what you mean when you say "the voltage across the inductor is leading the applied voltage".

Answer (score 1):

> The applied voltage is a sine wave. And the current must also be a
>   sine wave(albeit only for an instant)

On what basis do you say this. If the voltage is a sine wave the current is a cosine and vice versa.

> 1-Why are there three different waveforms here. If I measure the
>   waveform with an imaginary oscilloscope, I would get the applied
>   voltage. What are the other two telling waveforms telling us?

I believe there are only two waveforms involved, one for current and one for voltage. If the current is a sine wave then the derivative is a cosine for the voltage. The two waves are 90 deg out of phase.

> 2-Why is the current lagging?

The equation for the inductor can be rewritten:

$$i(t)=\frac{1}{L}\int_0^t v(t)dt$$

Where the initial current in the inductor is zero.

The integral tells us what is happening physically is it takes time for the current to build in an inductor, or to put it another way, you can't change the current in an ideal inductor instantaneously (in zero time). For this reason it is said that the voltage leads the current (or current lags the voltage) in an inductor. The voltage (emf) induced in an inductor resists a change in current. As time passes the current increases and the voltage decreases. The current is a maximum or minimum when the voltage is zero.

Hope this helps.

Comment: At the beginning, no current is flowing. So there is no change in current. But the current starts flowing at t=0. There has to be a change in current to generate opposition. The first change in current has to resemble the voltage which causes it right?

Comment: @underdog, what do you mean by "at the beginning" and "first change in current"? It sounds to me like you're picturing a circuit in your mind that is different from what you describe in your question.

Comment: @AlfredCentauri allow me to reframe my question. For an inductor to work there needs to be some change in current through it. Then this change in current induces an emf within it to counteract it. This counteracting emf is lagging the applied voltage by 90 degrees. But what is the nature of the waveform of the original change in current that caused all this. Should that not counitue to be the current waveform? Or otherwise what is the effect of the induced emf on the original current time varying waveform?

Comment: @underdog, First, it seems that you're thinking of the changing current as the 'first cause' but the equation $v=Ldi/dt$ doesn't imply that. Second, you seem to be thinking in terms of a turn on' transient problem rather than an AC (steady state) problem. Only in AC steady state can one say things like *the current lags the voltage by 90 degrees*. Third, emf *doesn't* lag the applied voltage by 90 degrees. For an ideal inductor, the emf is always equal in magnitude and opposite in sign to the applied voltage.

Comment: @AlfredCentauri If the emf is opposite in sign to applied voltage, then it means we are already taking the current to be lagging by 90 degrees.($-d(-cost)/dt)=-sint$ Assuming applied voltage is sint) How can I arrive at fact that current must lag the voltage by 90 degrees without assuming that to be so?

Comment: @underdog, I don't understand why you would think the first sentence of your comment is true. $\mathcal{E} = -v_L$ for an ideal inductor *regardless* of the form of the current through. I recommend that you examine the premises you're working from. At least one is wrong.